# How to check for duplicates and only append unique values in google-app-scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have the below code which helps me take data from sheet1 and pastes it in Sheet2

```
function HubArchive() 
{
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var sourceData = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  sourceData.splice(1,0);  // Remove header
  var rows = sourceSheet.getDataRange();
  var data = rows.getValues();
  var targetData = [];

  for (var i in sourceData) {
  if (sourceData[i][3] !== null && sourceData[i][3] !== 'test') {
    targetData.push(sourceData[i]);
  }
}
  var targetSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var targetRangeTop = targetSS.getLastRow(); // Get # rows currently in target
     targetSS.getRange(targetRangeTop+1,1,targetData.length,targetData[0].length).setValues(targetData);

}
```

However, I'm looking for a way for the code to check existing values in Sheet2 and only append any new ones instead of copying in any duplicates again. Any suggestions on what I could add in to make it check for duplicates and append only unique rows?

Comment: I'd recommend invoking a different function after updating the values to the target sheet. Perhaps check out [Removing Duplicate Rows in a Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/removing_duplicates).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You can do it with the help of [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), [array.push()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp) and [join](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp).

Sample:

```
function HubArchive() {
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var sourceData = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  sourceData.splice(1,0);  // Remove header
  var rows = sourceSheet.getDataRange();
  var data = rows.getValues();
  var targetSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");    
  var targetData =targetSS.getDataRange().getValues();
  var targetRowArray=[];
  for(var i=0;i<targetData.length;i++){
    targetRowArray.push(targetData[i].join(","));
   }
  targetData=[];
  for (var i in sourceData) {
    if (sourceData[i][3] !== null && sourceData[i][3] !== 'test'&&targetRowArray.indexOf(sourceData[i].join(","))==-1) {
      targetData.push(sourceData[i]);
    }
  }
if(targetData.length>0){ 
 var targetRangeTop = targetSS.getLastRow(); // Get # rows currently in target 
 targetSS.getRange(targetRangeTop+1,1,targetData.length,targetData[0].length).setValues(targetData);
 }
}
```

If you only want to compare the first column you can replace `[i].join(",")` by `[i][0]` :

```
function HubArchive() {
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var sourceData = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  sourceData.splice(1,0);  // Remove header
  var rows = sourceSheet.getDataRange();
  var data = rows.getValues();
  var targetSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");    
  var targetData =targetSS.getDataRange().getValues();
  var targetRowArray=[];
  for(var i=0;i<targetData.length;i++){
    targetRowArray.push(targetData[i][0]);
   }
  targetData=[];
  for (var i in sourceData) {
    if (sourceData[i][3] !== null && sourceData[i][3] !== 'test'&&targetRowArray.indexOf(sourceData[i][0])==-1) {
      targetData.push(sourceData[i]);
    }
  }
  if(targetData.length>0){
  var targetRangeTop = targetSS.getLastRow(); // Get # rows currently in target
  targetSS.getRange(targetRangeTop+1,1,targetData.length,targetData[0].length).setValues(targetData);
  }
}
```

Comment: Legend - thank you! What if I'm only looking for duplicates in the first column (A)? How can I modify ```&&targetRowArray.indexOf(sourceData[i].join(","))==-1``` to do the same?